# Column getting removed after retrieving data using ADOMD adapter if it contains (All) member in the entire column

Tags: c#-4.0, mdx, adomd.net

I am using the following C# code snippet for retrieving data from cube using a MDX query and ADOMD Adapter:

```
public DataTable GetDataTable(string query, string connectionString)
{
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    using (AdomdConnection cubeConnection = new AdomdConnection(connectionString))
    {
        cubeConnection.Open();
        try
        {
            using (AdomdDataAdapter adapter = new AdomdDataAdapter(query, cubeConnection))
            {
                adapter.Fill(data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception("An error occurred while retrieving the data");
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

The query I wrote returns the following result in SSMS:

[image]

After retrieving the data using the above code, the entire column is being removed as seen below (Screenshot taken from Data Table Visualizer in Visual Studio):

[image]

As seen above, the second column is being removed. Anyone has a resolution for getting the column into the data table?

Additional Information:

AdomdClient Dll Name: Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient

AdomdClient Dll Version: 11.0.0.0

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: SELECT {
 [Measures].[Unit Price]
} ON COLUMNS
,{[Product].[Color].[Color].MEMBERS-[Product].[Color].[]}
*[Product].[Name].[All]
ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works LT2008];


This query is fired on top of a custom cube built upon Adventure Works LT2008 database
Server Instance: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, although somewhat counter intuitive.  The number of dimension columns returned will based on the level returned minus one.

As you are only returning the a single level (i.e. All), ADOMD will show zero columns.  If you return two dimensional levels (i.e. All + Name) then you would see the Name column in your results.